# Get a collection of positive integers adding up to n

Tags: java

Consider the “sums to n problem:” given a positive integer n, list all the different ways to get a collection of positive integers adding up ton. Assume that we don’t care about order, so 1 + 2 and 2 + 1 are the same possibility.For n= 3, the possibilities are1 + 1 + 1, 1 + 2, 3

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

public class SumsToN { 
     static void listNumber(int arr[], int n, int i) 
     { 
         int MAX_POINT = 3; 
         if (n == 0) 
         { 
             printArray(arr, i); 
         } 
         else if(n > 0) 
         { 
             for (int k = 1; k <= MAX_POINT; k++) 
             { 
                 arr[i]= k; 
                 listNumber(arr, n-k, i+1); 
             } 
         } 
     } 


     static void printArray(int arr[], int m) 
     { 
         for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) 
             System.out.print(arr[i] + " "); 
         System.out.println(); 
     } 



     public static void main (String[] args)  
     { 
        System.out.print("enter n number: " );
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System. in);
         int n = input.nextInt(); 
         int size = 100; 
         int[] arr = new int[size]; 

         System.out.println("list of all the possibilities of "+ n + " are"); 
         listNumber(arr, n, 0); 
     } 
    }
```

My work is slightly incorrect as when i enter n = 5, it does not include for example 1 4 
and also it orders are wrong like  1+1+2, not 1+2+1---i.e., "order doesn't matter

Can someone help me with this please?

```
$ java SumsToN
enter n number: 5
list of all the possibilities of 5 are
1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 2
1 1 2 1
1 1 3
1 2 1 1
1 2 2
1 3 1
2 1 1 1
2 1 2
2 2 1
2 3
3 1 1
3 2

    $ java SumsToN
enter n number: 3
list of all the possibilities of 3 are
1 1 1
1 2
2 1
3
```

Comment: `k <= MAX_POINT` should be `k <= n-1`

Comment: Then, it never shows the result
"enter n number: 5
list of all the possibilities of 5 are "